# ArcGIS Server Java Edition - Deploy App to Embedded Tomcat

Tags: arcgis-server, tomcat

I am more experienced with the .NET side of the house, so please excuse me if this is a simple question.

Can I deploy an non-ArcGIS/ESRI app to the embedded Tomcat instance shipped with ArcGIS Server 10 SP5?  I have created a simple JAX-RS Jersey REST web service that pulls lookup values from MSSQL db to feed various widgets.  As this is (currently) the only component outside of ArcGIS Server ecosphere - I am hoping that I can use the embedded tomcat instance vs installing a more standard Tomcat instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is you could, but you shouldn't.

Messing with the internal Tomcat is not recommended and will likely give you issues with Esri technical support if you encounter issues with ArcGIS Server.

I have done some playing about with the internal Tomcat at 10.1 and the message from Esri is, don't do it (understandably as it might have knock on effects elsewhere).

Setting up Tomcat [is very easy](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37625) (at v7 it has a installer wizard for Windows platforms) and also means you can install a 64bit version of Tomcat.  You can set it up on the same machine as ArcGIS Server if need be, and you can tune its memory to not suck up too much resources from the machine.